# PHP set variable to json data

Tags: php, arrays, json, variables

**Hi guys I have a json out put that gives me data like this:**

```
{"results":[{"id":33424,"title":"Test","readyInMinutes":50,"servings":6,"image":"Random.jpg","imageUrls":["Random.jpg"]}],"baseUri":"Random.com","offset":0,"number":1,"totalResults":2323,"processingTimeMs":22323,"expires":33363}
```

How do I get the Title value and save it into a php variable? and how sdo i get the image variable from the json aswell?

**I have tried**

```
$recipieID =  $json->results[0]->id;
```

**And this works for the id**

**But if I try**

```
$pictureimage =  $json->results[0]->image;
```

**It does not work!**

Comment: Assuming you `json_decode()` the string and `id` is OK, I cannot reproduce the problem with `image`?

Comment: It works fine: https://ideone.com/cKhHWv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi guys It turns out I had missed the $json at the before the -> Thanks for the help!